# Yosemite: -[NSOutlineView _dataSourceValueForColumn:row:] EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

After upgrading to Yosemite, the app crashes when dismissing a NSSheet with a NSOutlineView.

The exception is BAD ACCESS.
It seems the datasource of the table is released too early. 
The datasource is bound in the xib file, and it is the File Owner, a NSWindowController. The table is populated overriding the datasource methods.

This is the exception stack:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tackled the same annoying problem with an NSTableView on an NSSheet. My code which worked prior to Yosemite was this:

```
[self.mainWindowController.window endSheet:self.fileRenamingWindowController.window];
self.fileRenamingWindowController = nil;
```

I would dismiss the sheet and purge the unnecessary window controller – worked like charm before Yosemite.

However, it seems that now the window and the corresponding view hierarchy doesn't get destroyed synchronously with endSheet:, so when in the above code the window controller is deallocated, the contents of the window will outlive it for a brief period (probably until the dismiss animation completes), causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS when e.g. an NSTableView has the destroyed window controller as its delegate/dataSource. I solved the problem by overriding the window controller's dealloc method to ensure that nobody (i.e. the tableView) holds onto it through weak references:

```
self.tableView.delegate = nil;
self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
```